# Fragment BackStack clears after loading the Image using Glide Image Library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-glide

I have used Glide for image loading (Image which is inside my fragment). And   handle the fragment backstack on backpress for navigating between the fragments. After loading the image my fragment backstack replaces with following fragment

com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment

entry so I'm unable to handle the backstack now, I don't want the glide SupportRequestManagerFragment to be attach in the fragment backstack also I have read the glide doc in the following link

http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#with%28android.support.v4.app.Fragment%29

They have mentioned that that passing context will attach the Glide to Application life cycle based on the context parameter. Now my requirement is that without affecting the fragment backstack how to load the image using glide, is it possible? or is there any other way to do it by configuring the Glide options?

Anyone help me or suggest the way to over come this issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have loaded the Glide with Fragment context

so that 
com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment

attached to the backstack, in-order to avoid the SupportRequestManagerFragment entry in backstack I have loaded the Glide with getApplicationContext() as mention in the below url.

http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/330/com/bumptech/glide/Glide.html#with%28android.content.Context%29

Comment: Thanks Man this is working for me i have added the getApplicationContext()  with getActivity() in fragment.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution, you saved me.  Thanks SO!